# Display of View (using grid) is unevenly distributed

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, theming

Note: as a neophyte user, I'm not allowed multiple links or images. It has been suggested that I edit the hyperlinks so they're not quite right. Hopefully you can sort out what's going on.

Here is my view with taxonomy terms in columns, but you see that the columns are a bit wonky and not evenly distributed. [image]

These are the the grid settings 
[image]

And this is the page h ttp://imgur.com/puH2v1M

Thanks.

Comment: Your View looks fine. It would be better to see the underlying html and the styles applied to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess (I cannot be sure without seeing the HTML and CSS) is that the grid display uses HTML tables to create the grid. Because this looks exactly like what HTML tables do: they adjust their column width to the content in it. For instance, "General Fiction" is longer than "Genre" so the first table column is wider than the second. Because your view is grouped, every group would render a separate table, so that's why the columns cannot align.

Assuming that tables are indeed the cause, the solution would be to add custom CSS setting the width of `<td>` elements in this view to `33.3%`. (How you can do that, depends on your theme setup and is beyond the scope of this answer.)